# when i use the create function using django rest framework it dosent create a new person

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

when i use the create function using django rest framework it dosent create a new person instead it shows an error `405 Method Not Allowed`. I even tried creating new person using frontend it just dosent work.

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def create_person(request):
    serializer = PersonSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

create.js:

```
const Create = () => {

    let history = useHistory();

    let [person, setPerson] = useState({
        name:"",
        about:"",
        email:"",
        image:"",
    })

    let createPerson = () => {
        e.preventDefault()
        fetch(`/api/person-create/`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "content-type": 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(person)
        })
        .then(setPerson({
            name:"",
            about:"",
            email:"",
            image:"",
        }))
    }

    let handleChange = (e) => {
        setPerson({...person, [e.target.id]: e.target.value});
        console.log(person)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("correct", person);
      }, [person]);
    
    return (
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            
            <form onSubmit={(e) => createPerson(e)}>
                <div>
                    <h2>
                        <button onClick={() => history.push('/')} className="btn btn-primary mt-4">
                            &#10094; Back
                        </button>
                    </h2>


                    <h2 className="mt-4 mb-4" style={{width: '600px'}}>
                        New Person
                    </h2>

                    <div className="form-group" style={{width: '600px'}}>
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name" value={person.name} />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group" style={{width: '600px'}}>
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">About</label>
                        <textarea style={{height: '250px'}}  onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" id="about" placeholder="Tell us somthing about yourself" value={person.about} />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group" style={{width: '600px'}}>
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email" value={person.email} />
                    </div>

                    <div className="custom-file mt-3">
                        <input onChange={handleChange} type="file" className="custom-file-input" id="image" value={person.image} />
                        <label className="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mt-4">Submit</button>

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>

        )
}

export default Create
```

i dont understand whats wrong here. i am pretty sure about the views and dont think that it is wrong not sure about the react part tho. any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Make sure you are posting to the right api?

Comment: yes i am cuz it says "POST /api/person-create/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5917  in the backend terminal

Comment: I would suggest rather doing `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` since you have no `else` condition which returns a response code indicating that there might possibly have been errors while validating data

Comment: it shows POST /api/person-create/ HTTP/1.1" 400 5824   400 is client side error

Comment: well i thought so cuz i was able to create new people using admin of django

Comment: do u see any problem in js part

Comment: You can then take a look at `serializer.errors` which would indicate what the issue is

Comment: how? can u please guide me

Comment: Just add else statement to the if, and return `Response(serializer.error)` or use debugger and set breakpoint on if

Comment: Are you sure that request.data in django contains any data? Just to eliminate the error from react part. Also, you are returning serializer.data even in case that the data is not validated.

Comment: you might wanna show how you created the serializer, and the model for the person if there is any.

Also 400 status code indicate "bad request", meaning you are sending the wrong form of data to the backend